# all combinations of boolean values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, boolean, combinations, php-7

Related to [Generating all the combinations of a set of boolean variables in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711260/generating-all-the-combinations-of-a-set-of-boolean-variables-in-haskell) and various other questions of the type.

I have a bunch of toggle switches in a database and want to get a list of all possible settings. *The number of switches can change*, specifically, users can add or remove.

I can get them into an array like

```
$switches = array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');
```

and I would like to generate all possibilities, i.e. something like:

```
$states = array(
array('aaa' => false, 'bbb' => false, 'ccc' => false),
array('aaa' => false, 'bbb' => false, 'ccc' => true),
array('aaa' => false, 'bbb' => true, 'ccc' => false),
array('aaa' => false, 'bbb' => true, 'ccc' => true),
...
);
```

I don't particularily care in which order the result set is.

What's an elegant way to generate that?

Comment: recursion would be the right approach here. You should be able to work something out based on the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556945/all-possible-combinations-in-array-recursion

Comment: did you *try* anything so far? personally, i'd count the switches, iterate from 0 to ^2n-1 and map the bits of the integer to the switches.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann That exactly what I offered in my answer :)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yes, I tried a naive recursive approach that didn't quite work out.

Comment: neither of the two answers given so far work if the keys are integers, btw.

Comment: @Tom as `$keys = [0, 1, 2];` ? I works fine for me

Comment: @dWinder I might've made a mistake in the data output behind your code.

Comment: @Tom so now it is give you the expected output?

Comment: didn't try so fast. :-)

Comment: @dWinder gave it a quick check and it seems to work, but I went with the other answer in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno if it's elegant, but for example use `array_reduce` with a callback:

```
$a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$states = array_reduce($a, function ($t, $v) {
    $newt = [];
    if (empty($t)) {
        $newt = [
            [$v => false],
            [$v => true],
        ];
    } else {
        foreach ($t as $item) {
            $newt[] = array_merge($item, [$v => false]);
            $newt[] = array_merge($item, [$v => true]);
        }
    }

    return $newt;
}, []);
var_dump($states);
```

Comment: replace the array_merge with the + operator and it works for numerical keys, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would have going or the idea of using the binary representation of integers (using [decbin](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php)):

```
$keys = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];
$n = count($keys);
for($i = 0; $i < pow(2,$n); $i++) {
    $num = array_reverse(str_split(decbin($i)));
    $res[] = array_pad($num, $n, 0);   
}

foreach($res as &$e) // adding the keys to the result
    $e = array_combine($keys, $e);
```

Notice the `decbin` can return string less then `2^$n` so I reverse the string and pad with 0 using [array-pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php)

Notice this will generate array with `0` and `1` instead of `true` and `false` but in PHP they very much alike - anyway, swapping them for true and false is easy enough so I leave it to you...